# Search for basic business-related Open Data standards

Tags: standards, metadata, business

What data standards, schemas or models are available to basic business/hr funcitons?

For example, a model for employees with information including address, contact information, metadata pertaining to the position(title, hire date, termination date, salary, etc.) and other basic information about people.

I did find the [HR "Open" Standards](http://www.hropenstandards.org/) that didn't allow downloading of the standard without joining and didn't provide an open license for consumers. I am working on a project across systems that will need to share common objects, I'd love to have a standard so that I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Please have a look at [The organization ontology](https://www.w3.org/TR/vocab-org/), and perhaps [schema:baseSalary](http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/terms?q=salary) would be appropriate for salary information.